# Not understanding a Possible definition for Not in Prolog

Tags: prolog

Started reading an introductory book on Prolog, and have come upon a possible definition for *not* predicate:

```
not(P) :- P, !, fail ; true.
```

As i understand, once P is evaluated the ! operator will commit its solutions and succeed. Later it will *fail*. what confuses me is the ; separation of *true* predicate: why is it not making the parent goalsucceed? In which point the negation of P occur?

Comment: It will not succeed, it avoids backtracing, and will `fail`. If `P` can *not* be satisfied, it will return `true`.

Comment: Wait to you find `\+ \+`, then it gets more confusing.

Answer (score 0):

```
not(P) :- P, !, fail ; true.
```

is better written as

```
not(P) :- (P, !, fail) ; true.
```

or even, breaking the "or" `;` into separate clauses:

```
not(P) :- call(P), !, fail.
not(P).
```

So it says you can state `not(P)` if:

- If you succeed in proving `P` (calling `P`) then

  - Commit to that solution via `!` (no trying again)
  - And then `fail`, so that `false` is the result of a successful proof of `P`
- Alternatively, if you have **not** been able to prove `P`, say you succeeded.

Thus `not(P)` should actually be read as "There is no positive evidence for P".

This is a strong hint that we are not actually dealing with classical logic here in spite of what's continually repeated.

See:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negation_as_failure

and the paper from 1978

https://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/~klc/neg.html

Comment: You did not mention closed world vs open world.